# Self learning neural network with Encog

Tags: java, neural-network, encog

Can a neural network(BP FF) self-learn(autonomously) how to control a propeller to avoid falling and stabilizing by trials?

Neural network type:  multi-layered, back-propagation feed-forward, sigmoid activation.

For simplicity, only vertical propeller control and vertical speed is taken.

İnput: vertical speed.

Output: propeller power(aimed only downwards so pushes only upwards)

Since a back-propagation NN gets error from difference of output and desired output, how can it teach itself without knowing the desired output(actually, it needs to learn desired output).

If I take error as vertical speed(stopped=no error), then it would be more suitable but how can I change the error function of Encog's ResilientPropagation or BackPropagation classes?

Do I need to write whole network class myself to achieve this type of learning? Because there is no initial training data. There is only newly created data from engine power and velocity.(If I can generate training data, then I would know how to control the engine so no NN is needed)

What is the most fitting neural network type for this job?

Comment: This is the problem of reinforcement learning. A full explaining of that field is, I think, out of scope for SO.

Comment: Can there be any chance with binding the output to an additional input so NN is aware of its output and somehow goes to minimize its error? Maybe vertical speed for intput+output(feedback) but only single propeller power as another output? I mean taking error of only one of outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment by @larsmans this can be solved by [Reinforcement Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) paradigm. In the context of neural networks currently the most popular (and only?) approach is to use two neural networks:

- actor network: which learns what action (propeller power in this case) the *agent* is ought to take in a given *state* (vertical speed in this case)
- critic network: which learns values, in the terms of future reinforcement *agent* can "hope" to achieve from this *state*

This approach is known as [Actor-Critic](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node66.html) methods. All you need to do additionally is to design the *reinforcement function*. In your case it seems quite simple, as it could be equal to the vertical velocity with additional penalty for deviating from some predefined height (otherwise the networks will learn just to wait a while till the propeller falls and stops for itself).

The main issue will be tuning all parameters for all of this to work correctly, however the problem seems very simple so it maybe not be very hard.

Comment: So critic produces an error(ver. speed) for itself and for actor. Then actor changes its weigths using the error and changes its propeller power output ? From new state of system, two NN get new input and produce new output(error & propeller). The only thing I add is reward?

Comment: Critic produces something like "expected reinforcement" or a "goodness of a state" including the context of future states reachable from this state. How "good" is a state is defined by your reinforcement function. The second link I've provided is to the key book in RL by Sutton&Barto. The whole book is freely available: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html. You will find very detailed explanations there.

Comment: Isnt this similar to altering a NN's training set with "goodness of a state" ? If a state is wrong side then alter that training ouput so it learns a better output for that input. Anyway, I will try first reinforcement one then alterable training-set one.

Comment: Yes, conceptually it seems very similar to altering the training set for the other network. However, as usually in such matters - the devil hides in the details :) Good luck!

Comment: It's not the only approach. Bandit gradient descent is a popular reinforcement learning algo, and I suspect it should work with backpropagation.